# Correct way to add multiple objects in indexedDb?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have the following array of objects which i want to add to and indexedDb:

```
const data = [
    { name: 'abc',
      color: 'blue'
    },
    { name: 'xyz',
      color: 'red'
    },
    { name: 'yui',
      color: 'black'
    }];
```

Now i create the database and insert this data into a store like this:

```
if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("people")) {
        peopleStore = db.createObjectStore("people", { keyPath: "name" });
        peopleStore.createIndex("color", "color", { unique: false });

        peopleStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            data.forEach(function(data) {
                operations.add(data);
            });
        };
    }
```

I have defined a function expression with an `add()` (inside a `const operations`) method like shown below:

```
add: function(data) {
            let request = db
                .transaction(["people"], "readwrite")
                .objectStore("people")
                .add(data);
        }
```

**So here are my questions:**

1. Is this way creating a new transaction every time the add() method
   is being called or is it inserting all data in a single transaction?
2. If it is creating a new transaction every time, how can i make only
       1 transaction to improve performance and perform all operations in
       it only. I am guessing i have to create a global variable with the
       transaction and perform operations on it (there are other methods too, like `edit()`, `delete()`, etc., with each one of them having a "`request`" variable inside them defining a transaction, similar to what i have shown above). 
   should i make a global variable something like this:

`const globalTrans = db.transaction(["people"], "readwrite").objectStore("people");`

3. Is creating a new transaction a costly operation?

Thanks in advance to everyone who takes their time to reply! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating global variable will create issue. It might be that a transaction is runing and for another operation you might overwrite it.

e.g -

```
var globalTx;
// let's say you are selecting data from people
globalTx = db.transaction(["people"], "read")  // in read access
// and at same time you are inserting data from employee
globalTx = db.transaction(["employee"], "readwrite") // in read write
```

There are many ways to solve the issue -

1. Create multiple methods based on scenario -

```
// for single value
function add(data) {
    let request = db.transaction(["people"], "readwrite").objectStore("people").add(data);
}

// for multiple value
function addMultiple(datas, callback) {
    const tx = db.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");

    datas.forEach(data => {
        let request = tx.objectStore("people").add(data);
    })

    tx.oncomplete = function(event) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

2. Modify the function to only receive array values -

```
// so now data will be only array    
function add(datas, callback) {
    const tx = db.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");

    datas.forEach(data => {
        let request = tx.objectStore("people").add(data);
    })

    tx.oncomplete = function(event) {
        callback();
    }
};

// so when want to insert single value , we will call like this.

const value = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'ujjwal'
}
add([value], () => {

})
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just a note... In your `function addMultiple(data, callback)` this line `let request = tx.objectStore("people").add(data);` should read `let request = tx.objectStore("people").add(value);`. NOTE the 'value' change

Comment: aha right, thanks for pointing out. Have updated codes.

Comment: How does indexedDB know when to commit the transaction? When is it going to call `tx.complete`?

Comment: So I don't have to check individual insert operations for errors and all I need is check it on the transaction level? And if one insert fails, will the whole transaction rollback?

Comment: when transaction created is inactive then it automatically commits

Comment: you can also catch error on each insertion or you can watch on the whole transaction. Indexeddb is transactional database, so if one of tx fails then whole tx is aborted.